# How can I debug seeds.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I am trying to insert some default users in my project using *seed.rb* file. I have executed the following line in the console:

```
rake db:seed
```

and no errors were thrown, but the records were not created either. When I paste the code in the rails console, again no errors are shown. I am guessing that I am doing something wrong in the *seed.rb* file.

This is how my models are related:

---

security_user.rb

```
has_one :security_users_detail, dependent: :destroy
has_many :security_users_manage_securities
has_many :security_users_roles, through: :security_users_manage_securities
```

---

security_users_detail.rb

```
belongs_to :security_user
```

---

security_users_role.rb

```
has_many :security_users_manage_securities
has_many :security_users, through: :security_users_manage_securities
```

---

And this is the code that I have in my *seed.rb* file:

```
users = {

   Admin: {

      Information: {
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: 'test',
        password_confirmation: 'test'
      },
      Details: {
        address: 'Not defined.',
        city: 'Not defined.',
        country: 'Not defined.',
        egn: '0000000000',
        faculty_number: '',
        first_name: 'Admin',
        gender: 'male',
        gsm: '0000000000',
        last_name: 'Not defined.',
        skype: 'Not defined.'
      },
      Roles: %w(Administrator)
   }
}

users.each do |user, data|

  security_user = SecurityUser.new(data[:Information])

  data[:Roles].each { |role|
    security_user.security_users_manage_securities.build(security_users_role: SecurityUsersRole.find_by_role(role))
  }

  SecurityUser.where(email: security_user.email).first_or_create!(security_user.attributes)

  security_users_detail = SecurityUsersDetail.new(data[:Details])
  security_users_detail.security_user_id = security_user.id
  SecurityUsersDetail.where(security_user_id:  security_users_detail.security_user_id).first_or_create

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the following line:

```
security_user = SecurityUser.new(data[:Information])
```

because even thought the hash passed in the new method holds only email and password fields, the result object was created with the rest of the model attributes but set to nil. For, example, I have  *id=>nil*.

Then in I was doing the following

```
SecurityUser.where(email: security_user.email).first_or_create!(security_user.attributes)
```

in order to created the user only if exists. Anyway, since the *id* parameter is not in the attr_accessible clause in the model, I was not able to make mass assign.

To delete the nil values of the hash I've done the following:

```
 SecurityUser.where(email: security_user.email)
              .first_or_create!(security_user.attributes
              .delete_if { |key, value| value.nil? })
```

Answer (score 4):

seed.rb is a rake task, so you can use `puts` to output messages to the console. For instance,

```
puts "User name: #{user.name}"
```

Comment: Also, to help you with your problem, it looks like you're calling `new` but never `save`.

Comment: Yes, I am calling first_or_create which will create a record if it is not found. If I executed all code in the rails console, will be the records inserted in the database?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, I think you have a bug in `security_user = SecurityUser.new(data[:Information])`. Is `data[:Information].present?` true? (Try using `puts`.) If not, you probably want `data[:Admin][:Information]`.

Comment: No, it is ok - I am using hash-value iterator and data is the hash of Admin.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help, it was more then one error in fact, but I was able to clear them.